# auto variables and auto objects memory allocation in a loop

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me how many times variable integer1 allocated and deallocated?
how about class_object? Is it true that both of them allocate and deallocate three times?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int integer1;
    Class1 class_object(some_parameter);
}
```

Comment: "As-if" rule will probably remove the inner `i`, and possibly the outer one too due to loop unrolling.

Comment: There are two distinct variables named `i`.   Neither of them are "allocated and deallocated" so your question is meaningless

Comment: *If* the compiler determines that it's necessary to reserve any storage space for automatic variables, it can be reused for objects with non-overlapping lifetimes.

Comment: If you wanted to ask whether the variables got created and destroyed three times, then yes they did. "Allocate" usually means something different.

Comment: I expect `integer1` could likely be allocated 0, 1 or 3 times depending on the compiler. The standard has this as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

For local variables allocation and deallocation is something compiler specific. Allocation/deallocation for local variables means reserving space on the stack.
Most compilers though will move the allocation and deallocation of the variables out of the loop and reuse the same space for the variable every time.

So there would be one allocation, meaning changing the stack pointer, before the loop and one deallocation, meaning restoring the stack pointer, after the loop. Many compilers will compute the maximum space needed for the function and allocate it all only once on function entry. Stack space can also be reused when the compiler sees that the life time of a variable has ended or that it simply can't be accessed anymore by later code. So talking about allocation and dealocation is rather pointless here.

Aren't you more interested in the number of constrcutions and deconstructions hapening? In that case yes, the constructor for Class1 is called 3 times and the destructor too. But again the compiler can optimize that as long as the result behaves "as if" the constructor/destructor were called.

PS: if the address of something is never taken (or can be optimized away) then the compiler might not even reserve stack space and just keep the variable in a register for the whole lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

For automatic (local stack) variables the compiler reserves some space on the stack.

In this case (if we ignore optimizations) the compiler will reserve space for `integer1` and `class_object` that most probably will be reused in each loop iteration.

For basic data types nothing is done beyond this but for classes the compiler will call the constructor when entering the scope of the variable and call the destructor when the variable goes out of scope.

Most probable both variable get the same address on each loop iteration (but this does not have to be true from the standards point of view).

The term `allocation` usually refers to requesting some heap memory  or other resource from the operating system. Regarding to this definition there is nothing allocated.

But assigning some stack space (or a register) to a automatic variables may also be called `allocation` most compiler will allocate memory once (by setting the stack frame to a value big enough on entering the routine.

Summary:
At the end it is totally up to the compiler. You are just guaranteed to get a valid object in its scope